# Delete action from timeline

Tags: php, http, facebook-graph-api, curl, http-method

Im using below php code to post an item to the timeline:

```
    $request_data=http_build_query(
    array(
    'access_token'=>'xxx',
    'item'=>'url'
    )
    );
    $c=curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/me/zoo:action');
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$request_data);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $result=curl_exec($c);
    $status=curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($c);
```

Im now trying to delete an item, but cant get my head around what the corresponding curl code would be. Facebook says:

```
    curl -X DELETE \
         -F         'access_token=xxxx' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/{'{id_from_create_call}'}'
```

Where in the first block of code would I define the "-X" and "DELETE" arguments?...

Thanks for any pointers!...

Answer (score 0):

You needs to send HTTP request with DELETE HTTP method instead of POST, which you define by `curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST,true);` call. Look for `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` option instead of `CURLOPT_POST` in the [curl_setopt doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Just replace

```
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST,true);
```

with

```
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"DELETE");
```

You can read [another post on the SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081894/handling-put-delete-arguments-in-php) for more details about custom requests.