# Oauth2.0 server in php very simple implementation - use access_token with POST

Tags: php, post, oauth-2.0

Im building a small API and want to use oAuth2.0 for login and token handling.

I have followed this step by step guide to get started: https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/

Now this all works fine I can get my `access_token` by sending post request to the token.php from the link guide above:

```
//GET TOKEN
$params = array(
  "client_id" => "testclient",
  "client_secret" => "testpass",
  "grant_type" => "client_credentials");

$test=curl_req($pageURL."/api/v1/"."token.php", $params, "POST");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
```

This outputs, as espected:

> ```
> stdClass Object
> (
>     [access_token] => b53a01a66d20760a8afef05bf36951eeba6b886d
>     [expires_in] => 3600
>     [token_type] => Bearer
>     [scope] => 
> )
> ```

Now I have the token and want to do a request to resource.php as in the example link above. But I want to do it with `POST`, not `GET` as in the step by step guide link above.

Is it possible to get the `access_token` verified with `POST` and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the command in the example is:

```
curl http://localhost/resource.php -d 'access_token=YOUR_TOKEN'
```

which actually issues a POST since CURL will revert to HTTP POST if the "-d" flag is provided, see the docs on "-d" at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

In general the OAuth server will be able to pickup to token if sent in any of the standardized ways, so a) in an "access_token" POST parameter, b) in an "access_token" query parameter (GET), or c) in the "Authorization: bearer" header. The last option is actually the preferred method since it prevents the access_token from mixing with user data (i.e. works also in non-REST environments) or ending up in logs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Didnt know the -d parameter was POST :) Could you give me an example how doing it with POST, using PHP? My curl_req method above, takes in the $url, $json to post, and $httprequest. I tried sending it as json "access_token:$token" via POST, but it dies. I also tried sending raw post access_token=$token with same result.

Comment: I'd recommend option c) :    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token));

Comment: the code in my previous comment shows how to send the access_token in an Authorization header in PHP using libcurl, which is an implementation of option c) in my original answer

Comment: Thanks, Im getting progress now. Im also using libcurl. But how does $access_token look in your example above? Is it just the raw key or in json or how?

Comment: Do you have the (required) space between Bearer and the actual token contents? The error is produced by: https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/develop/src/OAuth2/TokenType/Bearer.php maybe that will help. Seems to me it can't match "Bearer"

Comment: It was because Im also sending curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))); in that request. I cant use both headers at the same time, it seams..

Comment: you can but you need to add them both to the same array and set them at the same time

Comment: Yea you are right it works that way. but the data send is not recieved. Shouldnt it be printet using print_r($_REQUEST); in the resource.php?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending the access_token and POST data this way

```
$params = array(
  "client_id" => "testclient",
  "client_secret" => "testpass",
  "grant_type" => "client_credentials");

//GET TOKEN
$test=curl_req($pageURL."/api/v1/"."token.php", $params, "POST");
//        ^-- Im not using the curl_req2 function below here
// Im using a function, from my old question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420952/php-curl-delete-request

echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);

$token = array(
  "access_token" =>$test->access_token);

$data = array(
  "Some" =>"data",
  "More" =>"datatatat"
  );

// GET ACCESS using POST and POST data
$test2=curl_req2($pageURL."/api/v1/User.php",$token, $data , "POST");
print_r($test2);



function curl_req2($url,$token,$data,$req)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token['access_token']));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //$result = json_decode($result);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```