# Sending DELETE to API using PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I am brand new to using an API outside of an API wrapper.  I can access the API using

```
curl -u username:password https://company.c
om/api/v1/resources/xxxxxxx
```

That loads up all the information, but what I need to do is send a DELETE to the url based on an array of filenames; e.g. ['/js/jquery.js'].  The name of the parameter is Files.

I already have in code the directory and file name variables.

```
$storageFilename = $directoryname . "/" . $asset->name;
```

Above returns the /directoryname/filename from the database.

Comment: Sending DELETE request using PHP via CURL was described at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420952/php-curl-delete-request

Answer (score 0):

To send an HTTP(S) DELETE using the cURL library in PHP:

```
$url = 'https://url_for_your_api';

//this is the data you will send with the DELETE
$fields = array(
    'field1' => urlencode('data for field1'),
    'field2' => urlencode('data for field2'),
    'field3' => urlencode('data for field3')
);

/*ready the data in HTTP request format
 *(like the querystring in an HTTP GET, after the '?') */
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

/*if you need to do basic authentication use these lines,
 *otherwise comment them out (like, if your authenticate to your API
 *by sending information in the $fields, above. */
 $username = 'your_username';
 $password = 'your_password';
 curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
/*end authentication*/

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

/*unless you have installed root CAs you can't verify the remote server's
 *certificate.  Disable checking if this is suitable for your application*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//perform the HTTP DELETE
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

/* this answer builds on David Walsh's very good HTTP POST example at:
 * http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post 
 * modified here to make it work for HTTPS and DELETE and Authentication */
```

Comment: Good point.  I edited the answer to include login for APIs that use basic authentication.  (Some have you pass your authentication information as fields instead.  For those kinds of APIs just comment out the basic authentication lines.)