# How to delete a single Marketing Campaign recipient with API and PHP

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Trying to implement DELETE https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/{list_id}/recipients/{recipient_id} HTTP/1.1 in order to delete a single email recipient from a list, but I get this error message as the Result:  {"errors":[{"message":"no valid recipients were provided"}]}.

Here is the code, which I modified from [Sending DELETE to API using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541733/sending-delete-to-api-using-php?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
<?php

    $list = "971292";
    $recipient = "joe@joeblowxyz.com";
    $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/' . $list . '/recipients/' . $recipient;

    //this is the data you will send with the DELETE
    **# DO I NEED THIS?**
    $fields = array(
        'field1' => 'field1',
        'field2' => 'field2',
        'field3' => 'field3'
    );

    /*ready the data in HTTP request format
    *(like the querystring in an HTTP GET, after the '?') */
    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    /*if you need to do basic authentication use these lines,
    *otherwise comment them out (like, if your authenticate to your API
    *by sending information in the $fields, above. */
    $username = 'myusername';
    $password = 'mypassword';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    /*end authentication*/

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    /*unless you have installed root CAs you can't verify the remote server's
    *certificate. Disable checking if this is suitable for your application*/
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //perform the HTTP DELETE
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The error message, "no valid recipients were provided" makes me think I am supposed to use a numeric recipient id, but I haven't been able to find it for the email address in question.  Where is it?

In addition, is there anything else from the above code that is causing me problems?

Comment: Refresh the page and see if it improves.

Comment: ...otherwise go here:  http://rstunlimited.us/API-PHP-DeleteRecipient.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SendGrid -- How to delete a single Marketing Campaign recipient with API and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816612/sendgrid-how-to-delete-a-single-marketing-campaign-recipient-with-api-and-php)