# How to write PHP curl DELETE request

Tags: php, curl, digital-ocean

I'm referencing DigitalOcean's API docs, and they give the following example on how to delete a droplet here:

```
curl -X DELETE -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer API_TOKEN" "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/[DROPLET_ID]"
```

How can I write this in PHP curl?

I currently have this:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/18160706');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer MY_API_TOKEN')
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

But that is not deleting my droplet and is returning (Yes, the droplet id is correct):

```
{"id":"not_found","message":"The resource you were accessing could not be found."}1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP CURL DELETE request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420952/php-curl-delete-request)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This

Change the CUTLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST to "DELETE" [Find More](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/18160706');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Authorization: Bearer MY_API_TOKEN')
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: I used this to send a delete request, but still the API I'm interacting with (Mollie) doesn't allow it. They respond with a 405 status code and header `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE`. Any idea?

Comment: Same issue for me, with nginx, php-fpm and slim
everything works fine from swagger, but from phpunit test case it gives 
{"status":405,"error":"Method DELETE not in allowed methods (POST, GET)"}

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to `DELETE` as mentioned in the PHP Manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). Please take some time to read it. The following code should work

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result);
curl_close($ch);
```