# Http request via PHP

Tags: php, http, request

I have this code, usable via shell, but support told me it can be used in php too as http request. Can you tell me how?

```
           curl --include \
     --request DELETE \
     --header "Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj" \
 https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications/{notificationId}?app_id={appId}
```

Thank you

Comment: like the manual says: http://php.net/manual/de/curl.examples.php

Comment: @Najzero i don't understand how to send the "delete" request

Comment: Use this as your guide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420952/php-curl-delete-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see you argue with wax cage quite a bit, but yet you were friendly with me and my comment, so here goes.

Stackoverflow requires some basic understanding of the functions/api you try to use, using shortways and stackoverflow to code your code wont turn out well :-)

for CURL and the web and the PHP library, its setopt():

```
$curl = curl_init($url . "/Contacts/{$recordId}");
$curl = curl_init($url . "/Contacts/{$recordId}");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',"OAuth-Token: $token"));

// Make the REST call, returning the result
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (!$response) {
   die("Connection Failure.n");
}
```

( Taken from https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2013/08/30/doing-put-and-delete-with-curl-in-php/ )

Please lookup the oAuth token documentation, but I strongly guess your hash from the op goes there.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer **file_get_contents()** much more.

```
$arrContextOptions["http"] = array(
    "method" => "DELETE",
    "header" => "Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj\r\nContent-type: application/json",
    "content" => "",
    "ignore_errors" => true
);

$response = file_get_contents("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications/{notificationId}?app_id={appId}", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)));
```