# SendGrid -- How to delete a single Marketing Campaign recipient with API and PHP

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Will someone help me with the PHP code to authenticate my Sendgrid account connection and then delete a Marketing Campaign recipient via API?

From the help documentation, this appears to be the command line -- DELETE https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/{list_id}/recipients/{recipient_id} HTTP/1.1 -- but I can't figure out what to do with it, since it isn't regular PHP code.  The only sample code I found pertained to Legacy Newletters (which I got to work) and not contacts used by Marketing Campaigns.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to interact with the API? cURL? You just need to make an HTTP `DELETE` request to the url `https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/{list_id}/recipients/{recipient_id}`, replacing `{list_id}` and `{recipient_id}` with the IDs of the list and the recipient.

Here's an example of a function that will make a delete request for you with cURL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17935536/401096

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I have come up with so far (too long to post as an answer):  
http://rstunlimited.us/API-PHP-DeleteRecipient.html

Comment: Yes, you need the recipient ID, not the email address. It's returned upon creation of the recipient. You can also see it by iterating through your recipients https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#List-Recipients-GET. You can also see it in the URL if you look at your Recipients via the UI, e.g. `https://sendgrid.com/marketing_campaigns/ui/recipients/{recipient_id}`. Your DELETE request should not have a body payload.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do:  For internal purposes, I want to embed an unsubscribe link in the message that when clicked will run a PHP/cURL script to remove the recipient from my SendGrid Contacts list, as well as perform a certain task on my server.    API is the only method I see to do this on SendGrid, but I need to be able to pass the recipient_id automatically to the unsubscribe link -- for example like I can do with the email address [%email%].  So how can I get it from the database of contacts as the message is sent to each recipient?  (continued)

Comment: When I view a contact record I see the email address and first and last name, but no recipient_id field.  And there is no recipient_id field in the Tags list of the Campaign editor.  Bottom-line question:  Is the recipient_id even available for me to use the way I am asking?

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out?