# CodeIgniter Rest Server with Backbone, DELETE and PUT requests return 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I'm using backbone and CodeIgniter Rest Server,
The post and get requests from backbone works fine
But the put and delete requester gets 404 error with the response of {"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}

edit: I changed the source code to see which method codeigniter is trying to run
my controller url is

> `http://local/host/impacto/index.php/interviews/`

the put request url is

> `http://localhost/impacto/index.php/interviews/13`

and the function that codeigniter is running is 13_put instead of input_put

My controller

```
class Interview extends REST_Controller {

function __construct(){

    parent:: __construct();
}

public function index_get(){

    echo "get";
}

public function index_post(){

    echo "post";
}

public function index_put($id){

    echo "update: " . $id;
}

public function index_delete($id){

    echo "delete: " . $id;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling PUT/DELETE arguments in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081894/handling-put-delete-arguments-in-php)

Comment: not the same library, i'm using https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: I've hit upon exactly the same problem; sending a PUT to "Interview/{id}" calls the method "13_put()" and not "index_put(13)" as you'd expect ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Accordingly, it's not an error - https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/issues/255 - you have to either overtly specify "index" as the function ("Interview/index/{id}"), or alternatively give your method a name ("rest_put($id)", so accessed Interview/rest/{id}")

Comment: This is important as the controller has to know which method to call - it's receiving the parameter where it expects the method name. You could always try to use [`_remap`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) and route to the method you expect based on custom logic.