# How to get PUT/DELETE arguments in PHP

Tags: php, httprequest

i am writing a REST webservice and would like to know how can i handle put or delete argument is PHP.

i am taking the inputs as following,

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $input;
```

output = imei=1234567890&email=hello%40gmail1.com

how can i access these variables like

```
echo $_POST['imei'];
echo $_POST['email'];
echo $_GET['imei'];
echo $_GET['email'];
```

i found there is nothing like $_PUT or $_DELETE in php to handle the input params. what is the way to get this ?

Comment: You can encode it in the json format and then you can access them as a json object.

Comment: try this [parse_str](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2082120) may help. Be sure to check that your webserver supports PUT and DELETE requests and it it doesn't, try the given workaround.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you try this, PHP doesn't have a built-in way to do this, can be read from the incoming stream to PHP, `php://input`.

```
 parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars);
```

EX:

```
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    echo "this is a get request\n";
    echo $_GET['fruit']." is the fruit\n";
    echo "I want ".$_GET['quantity']." of them\n\n";
} elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
    echo "this is a put request\n";
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars);
    echo $post_vars['fruit']." is the fruit\n";
    echo "I want ".$post_vars['quantity']." of them\n\n";
}
```

Ref: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately php does not handle put or delete requests by default. I have created a library in order to handle this kind of requests. It also handles multipart requests (PUT PATCH DELETE etc)

You can find it here https://github.com/notihnio/php-request-parser

Comment: Whilst we love links in answers, we tend to discourage link-only answers as they are rendered useless when the link expires. Please update your answer with more information :)