# How to parse JSON decoded by cURL on PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I 'm trying to make some pages with php and curl using REST API. I can connect application and get all values as JSON format with curl on PHP. But, I can not parse values what i want.

I used this PHP commands for decode json values ;

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($data);
```

When I use this command i'm getting returning value like this ;

> Array ( [links] => Array ( ) [content] => Array ( [0] => Array (
>   [@type] => ConsumerEnt [links] => Array ( [0] =>
>   Array ( [@type] => link [rel] => GET: Request [href] =>
>   http.....
>   )  => Array ...etc

There are arrays inside arrays.. I could not find how to parse values i want. You can see values i want at following json codes;

Do you have any idea how it can be possible ?

Than

[You can see Decoded JSON by http://json.parser.online.fr/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deCBM.png)

```
{
  "links": [],
  "content": [
    {
      "@type": "ConsumerEnt",
      "links": [
        {
          "@type": "link",
          "rel": "GET: Request",
          "href": "https://ip/url"
        },
        {
          "@type": "link",
          "rel": "POST:Request",
          "href": "https://ip/url"
        }
      ],
      "entitledOrg": [
        {
          "tRef": "local",
          "tLabel": "local",
          "sRef": "768882f2-cf89-4cc8-92b7",
          "sLabel": "USsB01"
        }
      ],
      "citems": "a0221dfd-00f9-4019-95ed",
      "name": "NAME I WANT TO GET",
      "description": "Basic",
      "isNoteworthy": false,
      "dateCreated": "2016-09-25T11:44:02.698Z",
      "lastUpdatedDate": "2016-09-25T12:46:45.474Z",
      "iconId": "a0221dfd-00f9-4019-95ed-a74faeb2e1b2",
      "catalogItemTypeRef": {
        "id": "com.company",
        "label": "Compo"
      },
      "serviceRef": {
        "id": "7c92b9a5-9dd5-4819-9320-4127b1e3009d",
        "label": "NAME I WANT TO GET"
      },
      "outputResourceRef": {
        "id": "composition.type",
        "label": "test"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ConsumerEnti",
      "links": [
        {
          "@type": "link",
          "rel": "GET: Request",
          "href": "https://ip/url"
        },
        {
          "@type": "link",
          "rel": "POST:Request",
          "href": "https://ip/url"
        }
      ],
      "entitledOrg": [
        {
          "tRef": "local",
          "tLabel": "local",
          "sRef": "768882f2-cf89-4cc8-92b7",
          "sLabel": "astDF1"
        }
      ],
      "catalogItemId": "89b43bcb-4b23-4fc0-af26-66bd5c6bd1bc",
      "name": "NAME I WANT TO GET",
      "description": "RASDhFASel",
      "isNoteworthy": false,
      "dateCreated": "2016-10-27T07:55:03.243Z",
      "lastUpdatedDate": "2016-10-27T07:56:00.754Z",
      "iconId": "compos.png",
      "catalogItemTypeRef": {
        "id": "com.company",
        "label": "Compo"
      },
      "serviceRef": {
        "id": "7c92b9a5-9dd5-4819-9320-4127b1e3009d",
        "label": "NAME I WANT TO GET"
      },
      "outputResourceRef": {
        "id": "composition",
        "label": "Dep"
      }
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 2,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 1,
    "offset": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: What type of format actually you need?

Comment: You should start with the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: The parsing is perfect. You have to iterate through the array to get the desired result

Comment: @AHJeebon i need to text format. I need to list products in table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send JSON data to an API using PUT method via cURL/PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085967/how-to-send-json-data-to-an-api-using-put-method-via-curl-php)

Answer (score 0):

I guess i solved my issue like this ;

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($data);

  $j=count($data["content"]);

                for ( $say=0 ; $say < $j ; $say++ )
                {

                    print $data["content"][$say]["name"];

                }
```

as a result i can list my products ;

Product1
Product2
Product3