# How to access PUT parameters

Tags: php, yii2, put

I am using a php framework - `Yii2` for developing an `API` where I want to handle 4 types requests : `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`. Here I can catch the parameters in `GET` and `POST`, but I can't access the parameters in `PUT` and `DELETE` methods.

I had found some codes after a wide search. But it didn't work fine for me.
Sample code are:

**Sample 1 :**

```
$putdatafp = fopen("php://input", "r");
$putfp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$putdata = '';
while($data = fread($putfp, 1024))
    $putdata .= $data;
fclose($putfp);

var_dump($putdata);
```

**Sample 2:**

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$put_vars);
var_dump($put_vars);
```

But these two returns string datas. How can I parse the `PUT` and `DELETE` parameters into an array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081894/handling-put-delete-arguments-in-php

Comment: Yea thanks, Also I had changed the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Now its working :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling PUT/DELETE arguments in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081894/handling-put-delete-arguments-in-php)